# bootloop when trying to flash xposed

Tags: rom-flashing

so I used twrp to flash xposed-v86-sdk22-arm64.zip and then it got in a bootloop. I really want to have xposed on my 5.1 Samsung s6 can someone please help me

Comment: please note I'm a newbie when it comes to phones

Comment: The details you've given are extremely vague. Let's start by what rom you're running. Since you mentioned that you're a newbie, do share with us what link / tutorial you followed to get up to this point.

Comment: For Samsung devices you need a custom xposed build: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960

Comment: Have you made sure you chose the right zip for your architecture? Thats also very important to get it runninf